# How to mount swap encrypted with LUKS on boot?

Tags: encryption, swap, luks, cryptswap

I've got a LUKS partition at /dev/sdb8.
When I decrypt it, there's a swap space at `/dev/mapper/luks-bb0c88f3-1207-4db5-bb88-22a33c006d0b`.
What's the correct syntax for `/etc/crypttab`?

The partition is encrypted with a password. I want to activate it using UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to do it using GNOME Disks.

There's an option to decrypt LUKS partitions on boot. So, I've enabled that. Then, I used another feature of GNOME Disks, mount on boot. I set it to activate the swap space after it gets decrypted.